# How to get received message buffer from connected client socket using Socket and Reactive extension (Rx)

Tags: .net, sockets, c#-4.0, system.reactive, reactive-programming

As i am bit new to Rx and learning my way through it. I checked out lots of examples out there but none fits my need.

Scenario : I have one socket server socket (created using simple socket object and not TCPListener object). I have multiple clients (client socket and not TCPClient) connected to this server socket. I am trying to use Rx (Reactive extension) to get the messages sent by client socket by using "FromAsyncPattern" operator for BeginReceive and EndReceive asynchrounous operation.

I have almost started getting the messages in the buffer. But the issue is that the buffer return either the same message received from previous operation or will have mix content from current and previous receive operation.

Here is the code used :

```
    private void ReceiveMessageFromClient(Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[400];

                var functionReceiveSocketData = Observable.FromAsyncPattern
                                                            <byte[], int, int, SocketFlags, int>(socket.BeginReceive, socket.EndReceive);

                Observable.Defer(() =>
                                functionReceiveSocketData(buffer, 0, 400, SocketFlags.None)
                                ).Repeat().Subscribe(onNext: x => OnMessageReceived(buffer));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

OnMessageReceived method is just an delegate to raise the message received event and send the buffer to other class to process further.

**Problem :**  The same buffer is used evertime i get message how can i get the message received clean from previous received buffer.

-- What should be done if i have message received partially and the next message is actually part of this same message.

Please help me out with the above issue with some code snippets which would be greatful. Reason of posting this question is cause the implementation i have gone through till now are using TCPListener and here the constraint is to use socket object :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118289/using-reactive-extensions-rx-for-socket-programming-practical/3121205#3121205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're hitting is that you're sharing the same instance of your buffer between repeated calls to your observable. You need to ensure that you have a new buffer instance each time. It also appears that you should truncate the buffer based on the return integer. Here's what I suggest that needs to go in your `if` statement:

```
var functionReceiveSocketData =
    Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, SocketFlags, int>
        (socket.BeginReceive, socket.EndReceive);

Func<byte[], int, byte[]> copy = (bs, n) =>
{
    var rs = new byte[n];
    bs.CopyTo(rs, 0);
    return rs;
};

Observable
    .Defer(() =>
    {
        var buffer = new byte[400];
        return 
            from n in functionReceiveSocketData(buffer, 0, 400, SocketFlags.None)
            select copy(buffer, n);
    })
    .Repeat()
    .Subscribe(x => OnMessageReceived(x));
```

---

EDIT: In response to the comment re joining message parts. Also fixed the solution above - should be `0` and not `n` in the `CopyTo` function in the `copy` lambda.

I'm not an expert on using sockets, but, because the socket is (and correct me if I'm wrong) just a stream of bytes, you would need to be able to determine when each message in the stream is complete.

Here's one possible way to do it:

```
/* include `functionReceiveSocketData` & `copy` from above */ =

Func<byte[], byte[], byte[]> append = (bs1, bs2) =>
{
    var rs = new byte[bs1.Length + bs2.Length];
    bs1.CopyTo(rs, 0);
    bs2.CopyTo(rs, bs1.Length);
    return rs;
};

var messages = new Subject<byte[]>();
messages.Subscribe(x => OnMessageReceived(x));

Observable
    .Defer(() => /* as above */)
    .Repeat()
    .Scan(new byte[] { }, (abs, bs) =>
    {
        var current = append(abs, bs);
        if (isCompleteMessage(current))
        {
            messages.OnNext(current);
            current = new byte[] { };
        }
        return current;
    })
    .Subscribe();
```

The only thing you'd need to do is figure out how to implement the `isCompleteMessage` function.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good help. I just realized that i am still at -100 in Rx learning or may be i not just getting used to it to play well. The solution worked as well anyways.Sorry to push a bit more but can you suggest me some way to modify the logic to implement the receive in such a way that if i a message in two parts i can join them here it self and then push to the observers. I mean to say that as we used to use "object state" in Async call back-IAsyncResult we used to again call the receive function if we get anything again for this state.how can we achieve same scenario here ?? *Cheers*.

Comment: yes it did helped thanks again. Also learned to use Scan operator from Rx. One more question just popped in my mind just going through this.... is that....will this kind of Rx implementation for socket receiving will be faster than the traditional async socket receiving.

Comment: I don't think it would be any slower, but it uses traditional async sockets under the hood, so it could be slower. But the code should be easier to work with and less likely to be buggy so any (marginal) slow down would be worth it in robustness.

Comment: yah i can see that. The code is worth using. The problem here is repeat operator. When i add the repeat operator. The subscription doesn't stop even when socket object is null or closed. How can i stop the repeat process on some condition ??

Comment: Perhaps try using `TakeUntil` with a `Subject` as the parameter. You can then just call `OnNext` on the subject to stop the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the help again. Though i am not using TakeUntil but that help me click the answer in my mind. I have kept the Repeat operator as it is because i want a continuous results every time new message is received. After .Repeat() i have added a .TakeWhile() where in i check an condition (The above socket is null or not). If it gives null it stops the subscription. Please correct me if i am wrong. One more request. I know i have not still got rid of that .Repeat() so can you please give out some relevant example of your suggestion (TakeUntil) to remove .Repeat ?. Thanks again

Comment: `TakeUntil` will not remove the `Repeat`. It is used after the `Repeat` to end the sequence.