# Transformation of observable byte array to objects

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm using Reactive for the first time on a project and I ran into a problem where performance is very important.

### Overview:

I'm retrieving a large amount of data via a TCP socket, which I have to parse into objects and insert into a database. Each message has the following signature:

`<payload-size> <payload>`

Where size is uint32 (4kb) which describes the size of the following payload in bytes.

### Problem:

I want to use the functionality which the Reactive Framework provides to parallelize the following steps (seen below) to maximize performance and avoid being the bottleneck. Furthermore, I'm asking for a 'best practices' for implementing this.

```
TCP Socket ---> Observable (ArraySegment<byte>) --> Observable (Message)
```

I've already implemented the following code which provides me with an `Observable (ArraySegment<byte>)`.

```
IObservable<TcpClient> observableTcpClient = endPoint.ListenerObservable(1);
IObservable<ArraySegment<byte>> observableSocket = observableTcpClient
.SelectMany(client => client.ToClientObservable(bufferSize));
```

I now want to transform the `Observable (ArraySegment<byte>)` to an `Observable (Message)`. Where my first solution looked kinda like this because I though I could use an observable like a stream.

[Read continous bytestream from Stream using TcpClient and Reactive Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600011/read-continous-bytestream-from-stream-using-tcpclient-and-reactive-extensions)

### Question:

Will it be possible (and how) to create an observable using the following method? Or is there a better approach which you would recommend? I would really appreciate a good example.

Note: The Observable (ArraySegment) behave like a stream, so I do not know the size of the data it pushes to me. (Do I need to implement some kind of buffer or can the Reactive Framework help me?)

```
    Observable (ArraySegment<byte>) 
    --> Buffer(4kb) 
    --> ReadSize --> Buffer(payload-size) 
    --> ReadPayload 
    --> Parse Payload
    --> (Start over)
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm curious why you think parallelizing reading from a TCP socket (a stream) will improve any kind of performance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong :) What I'm after is having the retrieving logic running in a separate "thread" and have the transformation logic running concurrently so the data transformation won't block (Doing some heavy data transformations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up using. Feel free to comment with possible improvements.

```
    public static IObservable<DataMessage> Convert(IObservable<ArraySegment<byte>> bytes)
            {
                const int headerSize = 12; // bytes

                return bytes.Scan(
                    new
                    {
                        Leftovers = new byte[0],
                        Messages = new List<DataMessage>(),
                        Header = (Header) null
                    },
                    (saved, current) =>
                    {
                        var data = ConcatdArrays(saved.Leftovers, current.ToArray());
                        var messages = new List<DataMessage>();
                        var header = saved.Header;

                        while (true)
                        {
                            // Header
                            if (header == null && data.Count >= headerSize)
                            {
                                header = ReadHeader(ref data, headerSize);
                            }

                            // Payload
                            else if (header != null)
                            {
                                var type = header.Type;
                                var size = DataItem.Size(type);

                                if (data.Count < size) break; // Still missing data

                                // Create new message with the gathered data
                                var payload = ReadPayload(ref data, size);
                                messages.Add(new DataMessage(header, payload));
                                header = null;
                            }

                            // Can't do more with the available data - try again next round.
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        return new
                        {
                            Leftovers = data.ToArray(),
                            Messages = messages,
                            Header = header
                        };
                    }).SelectMany(list => list.Messages);
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** After Dimitri's comments, I present a revised solution below. There is one line in need of desperate refactoring, but it seems to work..

`Window` overload is used so we can write custom buffering.

```
var hinge = new Subject<Unit>();

observableSocket
.SelectMany(i => i) // to IObservable<byte> 
.Window(() => hinge) // kinda-like-buffer
.Select(buff =>
{    
    return
        from size in buff.Buffer(SIZEOFUINT32).Select(ConvertToUINT32)
        from payload in buff.Buffer(size)
        //Refactor line below! Window must be closed somehow..
        from foo in Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Do( _ => hinge.OnNext(Unit.Default)) 
        select payload;                     
})
.SelectMany(i=>i)
.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
.Select(ConvertToMessage);
```

**EDIT 2:** Removed old solution

Comment: Could you please provide full code example, because I made observableSocket = Subject<List<byte>>(); // your code;             observableSocket.OnNext(...); observableSocket.OnNext(...); and it does not work

Comment: Also your code is so hard to read and understand. Rx actually allows to run subscription on scheduler of your choice, we should not mix Tasks and Rx. The idea is to create a IObservable<IList<byte>> from initial sequence and then res.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance).Select(ConvertToMessage)

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly you are right, the answer is not complete as I said. That is a good idea to use `ObserveOn` to move data conversion to Threadpool and windowing could provide byte lists. I'll add a working example to the answer